# Call function after event is called from bootrap file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Theres a modal that open on click of some div .I want to extent the close or mouseout event of this modal(which is defined in bootrap.min.js).By extend I mean I want to call a function say foo() after the modal is closed from view. Is there any way i can do it in jquery?

```
function foo(){
alert("hiiii")
}
```

//i do not want to create another event because to do that i have to create two events Mouseout ,close(click in cross)
I hope i put my question well.

Comment: Sorry to say, but libraries aren't build like the way we want, sometimes we have to do unusual things to achieve what we want. Now in your case, bootstrap don't have any callbacks, instead it triggers events. So you have to bind event `hidden.bs.modal`. And also for `mouseout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this function. why MyModal as your modal id:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  foo()
})
```

for another functions you can find on the Bootstrap documentation

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/